# Actions for relativistic point-particles of higher spin

Tags: special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-spin, point-particles, higher-spin

To describe the behavior of a relativistic point-particle, we have the standard action
$$S=\int d\tau \bigg[\frac{1}{e} \dot X^\mu\dot X_\mu +m^2 e\bigg], $$
where $e$ is the worldline einbein. Then, it has been shown [arXiv:hep-th/9510021](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9510021) and [arXiv:hep-th/9508136](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9508136) that do describe a spin-1/2 particle, we must supersymmetrize the worldline reparameterization symmetry, yielding
$$ S=\int d\tau \bigg[\frac{1}{e} \dot X^\mu\dot X_\mu +\frac{i}{2} \psi^\mu\dot \psi_\mu +\frac{i}{e} \chi \psi^\mu \dot X_\mu \bigg], $$
where $\psi^\mu$ is the SUSY partner of $X^\mu$ and $\chi$ is the SUSY partner of $e$.

**Question:** How can we construct point-particle actions for higher-spin particles? E.g. what does the the action for a (massive or massless) spin-1 particle or spin-3/2 look like?